# Is there a native library written in Julia for Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, julia, flux.jl

I have started using Julia.I read that it is faster than C.
So far I have seen some libraries like KNET and Flux, but both are for Deep Learning.
also there is a command "Pycall" tu use Python inside Julia.

But I am interested in Machine Learning too. So I would like to use SVM, Random Forest, KNN, XGBoost, etc but in Julia.

Is there a native library written in Julia for Machine Learning?

Thank you

Comment: Deep learning is a flavour of machine learning, no?

Comment: BTW nothing is faster than C. But julia often comes close, and could in principle be as fast. A lot of people find it nicer and more productive to program in though.

Comment: Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Asking for an off-site resource is specifically off-topic.

Comment: [This](https://juliacomputing.com/domains/ml-and-ai.html) is the first result of a google search for "julia machine learning" and should be enough to get you started.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard that's a common thought, but is not true.  It is entirely possible for other languages to be faster than C.  Julia sometimes is, but we generally shoot for being within a factor of 2.  Check out all the languages we've measured to be faster than C here: https://julialang.org/benchmarks/ — Julia, LuaJIT, Rust, Go, and Fortran all beat C on some tests.

Comment: @MattB. thanks for clarifying. I wonder how that works - because the compiler can see some optimisations and removal of branches using the more high-level code than is possible in C? As I guess they should all otherwise in principle compile to the same machine code.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard a [concrete example](https://github.com/dyu/ffi-overhead), JIT links to dynamic libraries similar to static libraries since they already load in memory at "compile time", thus skips a table looking in the generated code.

Comment: @Prune What do you mean by off-site resource?

Comment: That's a resource not on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of algorithms are just plain available using dedicated packages. Like [BayesNets.jl](https://github.com/sisl/BayesNets.jl)

For "classical machine learning" **[MLJ.jl](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/MLJ.jl)** which is a pure Julia Machine Learning framework, it's written by the Alan Turing Institute with very active development.

For Neural Networks **[Flux.jl](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl)** is the way to go in Julia. Also very active, GPU-ready and allow all the exotics combinations that exist in the Julia ecosystem like **[DiffEqFlux.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DiffEqFlux.jl)** a package that combines Flux.jl and DifferentialEquations.jl.

Just wait for [**Zygote.jl**](https://github.com/FluxML/Zygote.jl) a source-to-source automatic differentiation package that will be some sort of backend for Flux.jl

Of course, if you're more confident with Python ML tools you still have [TensorFlow.jl](https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl) and [ScikitLearn.jl](https://github.com/cstjean/ScikitLearn.jl), but OP asked for pure Julia packages and those are just Julia wrappers of Python packages.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this kNN implementation](https://github.com/KristofferC/NearestNeighbors.jl) and [this for XGboost](https://github.com/Statfactory/JuML.jl).

There are SVM implementations, but outdated an unmaintained (search for SVM .jl). But, really, think about other algorithms for much better prediction qualities and model construction performance. Have a look at the OLS (orthogonal least squares) and OFR (orthogonal forward regression) algorithm family. You will easily find detailed algorithm descriptions, easy to code in any suitable language. However, there is currently no Julia implementation I am aware of. I found only Matlab implementations and made my own java implementation, some years ago. I have plans to port it to julia, but that has currently no priority and may last some years. Meanwhile - why not coding by yourself? You won't find any other language making it easier to code a prototype and turn it into a highly efficient production algorithm running heavy load on a CUDA enabled GPGPU.

I recommend this quite new publication, to start with: [Nonlinear identification using orthogonal forward regression with nested optimal regularization](http://centaur.reading.ac.uk/39716/)